# Why is an interface now picking up a dhcp address after updating from 18.04 to 20.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, 20.04, dhcp, netplan

I run ubuntu as a server and I have set a static IP address using netplan. Since I have updated from 18.04 to 20.04, eth0 has now started picking up a DHCP allocated IP address in addition to the static ip I have already set. I went into the netplan yaml config file and added `dhcp4: no` for the interface, but it still picks up the dynamic IP.

I checked the DHCP service running on my router and I can see the lease there

Any ideas what is making the interface DHCP enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was dhcpd running that was requesting an IP address. I disabled it and problem solved.